# Joining MySQL table that is not directly related

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that joins a 2 tables based on the relation by the table to a 3rd table, but it doesn't always seem to working fully.  The query is:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ECPCodeID, a.RegDate, a.BusName, b.ID as RepCodeID, b.RepCode 
FROM ECPs_Registration a, Reps_Codes b 
WHERE SUBSTR(a.ZipCode,1,5) 
IN (
   SELECT SUBSTR(c.Zip,1,5) 
   FROM Reps_Zip c
   WHERE c.RepCodeID = b.ID
)
ORDER BY b.RepCode,a.BusName
```

If I take out the Rep_Codes table from the main join and put it in the Reps_Zip select, it works, but I don't get the fields from the Reps_Codes table that I need:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ECPCodeID, a.RegDate, a.BusName
FROM ECPs_Registration a
WHERE SUBSTR(a.ZipCode,1,5) 
IN (
   SELECT SUBSTR(c.Zip,1,5) 
   FROM Reps_Zip c, Reps_Codes b
   WHERE c.RepCodeID = b.ID
)
ORDER BY a.BusName
```

How would I change this to get the same result as the second query, but get the Reps_Codes fields in the result?

EDIT:

I get the same result as the first query if I do:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ECPCodeID, a.RegDate, a.BusName, b.ID as RepCodeID, b.RepCode  
FROM ECPs_Registration a, Reps_Codes b, Reps_Zip c   
WHERE SUBSTR(a.ZipCode,1,5) = SUBSTR(c.Zip,1,5) AND c.RepCodeID = b.ID
ORDER BY b.RepCode,a.BusName
```

What I am looking for is to get all the records of ECPs_Registration table and then get some information for that record from Reps_Codes table.  That Reps_Codes connects to the ECPs_Registration by a third table Reps_Zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with the queries, it was an issue where the Reps_Zip had duplicate zip codes in it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that your ECPs_Registration and Reps_Codes don't know how to "align" together. You need to tell MySQL what relationship they have together. You can do that with a JOIN or a WHERE clause.

What you need to understand from your query is that you made your WHERE ... IN clause act like a filter, not a joiner.

You might want to try this (no guarantee on performance):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ECPCodeID, a.RegDate, a.BusName, b.ID as RepCodeID, b.RepCode 
FROM ECPs_Registration a
INNER JOIN Reps_Zip c ON SUBSTR(a.ZipCode,1,5)=SUBSTR(c.Zip,1,5)
INNER JOIN Reps_Codes b ON c.RepCodeID = b.ID
ORDER BY b.RepCode,a.BusName
```

Comment: I realize that is the case, just don't know how to relate them.  I put in an edit above another query that I tried.  Tables a and b are connected by c.

Comment: Thanks, that still gives me the same result as my first and third queries.  It displays more results than there are records in ECPs_Registration.